# Peticiones HTTP con React-Native no funcionan en Android

Tags: javascript, nodejs, react-native, programación-móvil

les comento que Al trabajar con peticiones al servidor usando **Fetch** y tambien usando **Axios**, al ejecutarlo en android me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: Error Image]

```
fetch(URL,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
                email: userEmail,
                password: userPassword
            }),

        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson)=>{
             Alert.alert("bien");
       console.warn(responseJson);
             })
         .catch((error)=>{
         console.error(error);
     console.warn(error);
   });
```

No es el servidor puesto que la api ya se usa para otro tipo de aplicaciones, y en iOS funciona perfectamente

Comment: y como haces la llamada? coloca el código, una imagen del error no es mucha ayuda.

Comment: @WFgo ya te lo actualize, igual pasa lo mismo con cualquier tipo de petición.

Comment: cual es la url a la que apuntas? una url externa o local?

Comment: Es una externa.

Comment: estas corriendo android en un emulador? si es asi, vas a tener que cambiar el localhost del emulador a la ip local de tu maquina para que funcione.

Comment: @WFgo , Bueno la prueba fue realizada en un emulador y un dispositivo( en ambos dio el mismo error), el del screen es un dispositivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, El problema era con el certificado SSL de la url.

Segun la documentación de android: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) en la sección "Problemas comunes de la verificación de certificados del servidor", en el subtema : Falta de autoridad de certificación intermedia", el cual no permitía el acceso a la api.

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más por si a alguien le pasa en un futuro o a tí mismo?